# How to commutate quarters of a sinewave

Tags: switches

In the image bellow you can see a sinewave, it is from a 20V, 50Hz system.

You can see four loads, 1 to 4 which I need to switch on and off every quarter of the sinewave.

Could you please advise how to commutate the load? I think quarter 2 and 4 I can switch on/off with a TRIAC, but what about quarters 1 and 3? Could you please suggest how to arrange it best way?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, even if I don't really understand what you want. What exactly are you trying to achieve? A triac can work in 4 quadrants. Why do you need your load "commutated"? What load is this? For what purpose?

Comment: A TRIAC can turn on in all four quadrants, but it does not turn off until the current through it is less than its holding current, essentially zero.  The OP is correct, this happens only in 2 and 4.

Comment: Commutation is one issue, easily solved with phase and comparator detectors but what is the load (s)?

Answer (score 0):

A TRIAC can turn on in all four quadrants, but it does not turn off until the current through it is less than its holding current, essentially zero. The OP is correct, this happens only in areas 2 and 4 of his diagram.

One option is to use a GTO.  Not the muscle car of the '60s, a gated turn-off SCR.  Without knowing more about the load and the application, this is just a guess.

Another option is two NPN and two PNP transistors, one for each quadrant as appropriate, plus the associated level-shifted control signals.  Can't recommend parts without knowing the current being switched.

For total control and less power loss, but more cost and complexity, four pairs of back-to-back power MOSFETs can do just about anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd break the question down to two partial problems:

1. detect quadrant transitions. Note that two of them feature zero crossings on the sinewave. If you phase-shift the sinewave by 90*, e.g. using an [integrator or a differentiator](https://www.elprocus.com/what-is-an-operational-amplifier-op-amp-integrator-and-op-amp-differentiator/), you can then detect zero crossings on the shifted wave, and thereby get the other two points. Or you can just detect instantaneous polarity, on the original sinewave and the phase-shifted copy, and combine the the "detection results". This could be cobbled together using comparators / op-amps and post-processed by further logic. Or you could use an MCU with an ADC channel and do the logic in software.
2. how to commutate a load: there's a popular device that happily turns on/off almost instantaneously, and it's called the transistor. FET or BJT does not matter much - although each needs a different driver circuitry.

Next, there are some pesky circumstances and additional aspects:

- what style of load. Only pure resistive load makes no objections when switched on/off arbitrarily. Inductive load doesn't like being switched off while current is flowing, which can easily be during a voltage zero crossing. Light bulbs have an ugly inrush on startup, lasting a fraction of a 50Hz period.
- what voltage / signal levels do you need to work with (detect / commutate)? If too high for small-signal silicon, you may need to transform the sinewave down to a bearable level for "signal processing". Using a transformer or a resistive divider. EDIT: those 20 Volts - does this apply to signal detection and load switching?
- what power or current do you need to commutate? There's a broad range of power transistors and IGBT modules on the market...
- can you switch the load to a ground (low side switch), which is easier to implement, or do you need to switch the load at the high side = to some power rail?
- would you prefer to have the switched circuit isolated from the quadrant-detection and control logic? You might be interested in IGBT's, or build an opto-coupled driver circuit out of stand-alone devices...
- how to provide power supply to the detection logic and driver circuitry, which gets especially interesting when galvanic isolation needs to be implemented